# What is the concise way to map error of an Either type in scala

Tags: scala, either

I need to change the error type of Either in scala.

For example, I have input type `Either[String, Long]` and need to convert the output type as `Either[Exception, Long]`.

Below is the sample program -

```
  val e2: Either[String, Long] = Left("exception 2")

  val e3:Either[Throwable, Long] = e2 match {
    case Left(ex) => Left(new Exception(ex))
    case Right(l) => Right(l)
  }
```

match seems bit verbose here.  is there better way to do this?

Note: I'm not using advanced library like cats/zio/monix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use left projection ([`Either.left`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/util/Either.html#left:scala.util.Either.LeftProjection%5BA,B%5D)) with map:

```scala
val e3 = e2.left.map(new Exception(_))
```

Comment: Worth adding that if you have **cats** in scope you can also use `leftMap` or `adaptError`